# Outlook addin not appearing in outlook 2013 windows client

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, outlook, outlook-addin

I have developed a simple app and added it to my account as the tutorials have said:

- click manage apps
- add manifest file

The app uploads and works fine in the web based outlook client, but does not appear at all in the windows client (office 365 account running outlook 2013 windows client).

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the 1.1 scheme and javascript API, I found changing to 1.0 (changing the manifest scheme and any API calls that didn't work in 1.0) made it show up and work.

Not sure why 1.1 didn't work in my outlook windows client as I have an up to date version of 2013...